# Redirect www to https after messing up config files

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I got an SSL certificate from Let's Encrypt and after messing up the installation with bad selections at the installation process, I believe I got some broken code in the `000-default.conf` file, because currently only if I type `example.com` it redirects me to `https://example.com/`, but when I type `www.example.com` it leaves me at `www.example.com` without HTTPS. this is how `000-default.conf` currently looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Edit: Let's Encrypt created more files inside sites-available, alongside 000-default.conf, so I assume you need all them to work together, such as the following file: `000-default-le-ssl.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
ServerName example.com
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have certificate for both www.example.com and example.com.
What do I need to edit to prevent www.example.com access to regular HTTP and redirect it to HTTPS? I can't find out

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to include the server name and alias to your virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName website.com
  ServerAlias www.website.com

  RewriteEngine On 
  RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]    
</VirtualHost>
```

This will force both urls to be redirected. Note that your rule used to be limited to non-www url.

Comment: That didn't work, I think it has something to do with the fact that it redirects using Rewrite Engine inside a virtual host?

Comment: Looks like your condition of rewrite was the problem. See my updated answer

Comment: Didn't work, I edited my question: added another file that Let's Encrypt added: `000-default-le-ssl.conf`, so I guess you need all to work together? Also, found a workaround: to add another <VirtualHost *80> with write condition www.example.com

Comment: Update: I had a typo, your edited solution works. Why you changed NE flag to QSA? and why completely removing that middle line worked? Or you need both changing NE to QSA and remove the line?

Comment: The middle line meant it will only redirect if the host name is "example.org" and it will ignore `www.example.org` which was the cause to your problem. As for the flag, we just want to [append the Query Strings if there are any](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

Comment: Thank you sir! BTW, was my earlier workaround OK?
What I did was to copy the entire `<VirtualHost *:80>` block and only changed `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com` to `RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com`. It worked, but maybe it might caused problems in the future? Also your solution works without `ServerAliasexample.com`, maybe because it's on the other file

Comment: Glad it worked. this is the usual way to redirect all traffic to ssl without having to manually add a subdomain every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can just tell it to redirect port 80 to port 443, that's where I'm guessing you are running your ssl, here is an example:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: but I used Let's Encrypt and it created 2 config files wih <VirtualHost 443>, will that not mess them up?